# jQuery ui dialog boxes not draggable and resizable after appendTo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, appendto

I am implementing sticky notes using jquery ui dialog boxes. On a button click a big full screen ui dialog box is opened and inside that big dialog box is a button to add small dialog boxes (notes).

**HTML**:

```
<body>

  <button id="opener">open the dialog</button>

  <div id="outter-dialog" title="Notes">
    <button id = "add-note">Add Note</button>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
$( "#outter-dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Success Message",
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height(),
        modal: false,
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});

$("#opener").click(function(){
    $( "#outter-dialog" ).dialog('open');
});


var prevelement;
$("#add-note").click(function () {
    var dynamicDialog = $('<div id="MyDialog"> <textarea>Hello</textarea> </div>');
    var pos;
    if (prevelement) {
        pos = {
            my: "left",
            at: "bottom",
            of: prevelement
        }
    }

    dynamicDialog.dialog({
        title: "Note",
        modal: false,
    appendTo: "#outter-dialog",
        buttons: [{
            text: "Save",
            click: function () {}
        }],
        position: pos
    });
    prevelement = dynamicDialog
});
```

Now I have an issue when I add `appendTo: "#outter-dialog"` to my dynamic small dialog boxes (notes):

after appending them to outter dialog box **they are no longer resizable and draggable**.

I appended them to outter dilaog box so that on open/close of outter dialog box inner notes are shown/hidden.

Any idea why they are not draggable and resizable??

Comment: you have to delegate the event for dynamically generated html see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960144/jquery-draggable-not-working-for-appended-table-row

Comment: @Kartikeya: I tried `$( "#outter-dialog" ).on( "mouseover", ".MyDialog", function( event ) {
var elem = $( this );
    alert(elem.text());
    elem.dialog("option", "resizable", true); 
  });
` . But still it's not resizable. Any idea??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the way you can overcome the issue, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vrohsv9g/4/)
Just set the `dragable` and `resizable` to `false` and call them separately once you create the dialog. and remember to clone the dynamic element and use dynamic id for that element

```
var elementCount = 0;
$("#add-note").click(function () {
    var dynamicDialog = $('<div> <textarea>Hello</textarea> </div>');
    var pos = {
        my: "left",
        at: "bottom",
        of: "#dialog" + elementCount
    }

    var dialogId = "dialog" + elementCount;
    dynamicDialog.clone(true).attr("id", dialogId).dialog({
        title: "Note",
        modal: false,
        appendTo: "#outter-dialog",
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: [{
            text: "Save",
            click: function () {}
        }],
        position: pos
    });
    $("#" + dialogId).parent().draggable().resizable();
    elementCount++;
});
```

Comment: `appendTo` does not work as it was added in version 1.10

Comment: `appendTo` of dialog box, I meant.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Updated the working answer for you :)

Comment: Above answer works but now positioning of new notes is not side by side, they are `bottom`. After trying `top` too new notes don't move side by side. Any idea?

Comment: They are one below the other. I meant one besides the other

Comment: Is ther a way to position a new note in the next row when a new note created reaches screen width?? So like after 3 notes creation a scroll comes as 4th note is positioned on right side of the 3rd.

Answer (score -2):

```
$( "#outter-dialog" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
title: "Success Message",
width: $(window).width(),
height: $(window).height(),
modal: false,
resizable: true,
draggable: true,
buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
         $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```